# Stackoverflow Editor is openSource and Java Integration?

Tags: java, web-applications, editor, stack-overflow

I have one question in mind ,Is **Stackoverflow** Editor is open source ? And if yes how can we integrate it with Java Web Application? Becuase its very simple and understandable by everyone .

Answer (score 2):

Stackoverflow uses the [pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) editor.

Comment: DO you know any example how can we integrate it with Java Web application?

Comment: The Editor can be integrated in any website, because it is pure JavaScript and the MIT-License also allows you to use it in commerical products.

Comment: @subodhjoshi No, but stackoverflow users [markdownsharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) on the server and that can serve as a reference for integrating into a Java environment.

Comment: hmm its looking c# based